# How ignored the modified /deleted files in Mercurial

Tags: regex, mercurial, tortoisehg, ignore, hgignore

[image][image] I write in the file .hgignore to ignore the modified file but I found that only the file at the begining of that line ? and for M, ! , R is not work.

syntax: regexp

^(.+/)?project/.project$
^(.+/)?target$

^(.+/)?.idea$
^(.+/)?.idea_modules$

^.+.(scala|sc|xml)$

Comment: Please clarify your problem. What exactly 'does not work'? What exactly is your goal? What exactly did you try? Is that a quote from the .hgignore you tried? What do you see on your repo (output of `hg st`) when using it? What do you expect to see? Give examples for both!

Comment: I want to ignore file that begin by M and ! but I can't

Comment: Did you simply try "M.*" and "§.*"?

Comment: I add a picture for the file that I want to ignore @ planetmaker

Answer (score 2):

`.hgignore` only ignores files that aren't already under source control.  Files marked `M` are under source control but have uncommitted modifications.  Files marked `!` are also under source control but are deleted in your current working directory.

In summary, only files with a status of `?` (not under source control) can be ignored.

Comment: So How can I setting the mercurial to never show this files. other thing I work with Intellj idea. @ Mark Tolonen

Comment: @kamkimo, `hg forget` the files so they aren't under source control.

Comment: when I do hg forget and  I compile the project, the file modified is show anther time.

Comment: @kamkimo, what does "the file modified is shown another time" mean?

Comment: yes after I forget and I compile it's shown another time.